# Why are the card links broken?

Tags: bug, magic-the-gathering, mtg-autocard

I've seen here many people use a specific syntax to have a link added automatically:

example: [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d)

The problem is that those links, pointing to Wizard's website are broken. Who's in charge of fixing that? This could be done either by fixing the way the searches are sent to Wizards, or by using another source like magiccards.info of scryfall.com?

Is there some source code available for the whole thing?

This is annoying, as if you don't know the cards, you have to search separately and do multiple copy-paste.

Comment: The issue may be that the card name is not spelled correctly as I have run into that in the past where fixing the spelling fixes the link.

Comment: This is not the case. In the example I gave, Lightning Bolt is correctly spelled.

Comment: What is broken about that link? It directs to the Lightning Bolt Gatherer page just like it is supposed to

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm on Firefox and the link doesn't work for me

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox. What sort of error are you getting? And are you able to get to Gatherer normally? http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx

Comment: This is the URL I get, and the gatherer answers "Your search returned zero results;": http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d

Comment: It all boils down to `+[Lightning]+[Bolt]` versus `+[Lightning Bolt]` in the search. The first works, the second doesn't. When I look to the web page source, that's the second that is here, so I don't understand how it can work for you.

Comment: That link works just fine for me, so I'm not sure why it isn't working for you

Comment: Could you please right click on the link, select "copy the URL" and paste it here please?

Comment: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d

Comment: This is the link that works for you? It definitely doesn't for me.

Comment: This is what I get with your link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCO2U.png

Comment: Does this link work for you? http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name="%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d"

Comment: In a comment below, I posted a link to what Wizards advices to use in link construction, which is the +["Card Name"] syntax. You're using "+[Card Name]", which has the same effect, but is less standard. Both have the same drawbacks. If you know programming, I've made some unit tests to check the syntaxes and their limitations. The code lies at https://github.com/liberforce/mtg-urlcheck and is under developement.

Comment: All in all, the only way to fix this correctly is to use the official API to get card information. The "find card by name" use case is documented there: https://docs.magicthegathering.io/#advancedcards_get_by_name

Comment: @liberforce did the link I posted in a comment work for you?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the preferred link notation. One should use `+["Card Name"]` instead of `"+[Card Name]"`, but they give the same results, and have the same limitations.

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause of a failure like this is Gatherer operating in a language other than English. On the [Gatherer Settings page](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Settings.aspx), the bottom option allows you to set a preferred language. Setting that to English may fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for finding the root cause. The problem is that this seems to be set by default depending on the locale preferences of the user, so that means all non-english users have a broken search by default :(

Comment: This is especially annoying as websites like magiccards.info handle the searches in multiple languages. I wonder if there is a way to force the en-US in the URL ?

Comment: you can always link directly to the cards, ie [Bear Cub](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6613). But I believe most people link using the `[mtg:   ]` shortcut

Comment: In fact I saw on Wizards site. They explain how to setup quicksearches on firefox, and how to forge the search link from a card's name. And the way they use it is clear: the name of the card must be enclosed in double quotes characters. This way you don't rely on the cookies of the user. This means boardgames was broken for all non-english users that didn't configured their cookies on the gatherer : http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Help.aspx#firefox

Comment: So, I go back to my questions: who has the code so he can fix it? It's a 2-characters patch!

Comment: @Malco Even if you do link directly to a card page, there are editors who will go through and change the format of links. That has happened to several post I have seen, particularly an issue for cards with names that match other cards, since the API uses a search.

Comment: @Andrew did the edits go through, or were they only in the suggested queue? If someone replaces your direct gatherer link with a broken autocard link then unfortunately you will just need to go in and edit it back leaving your reason for doing so in the edit reasons. If they replace it with an autocard link that isn't broken then I would recommend you leave it as there is a chance that autocard might be getting tweaked/fixed in the foreseeable future. Drop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) if you would like to discuss this a bit more.